# QComboBox's right button covers the last character of the string

Tags: qt

As the title mentioned, the combobox's width is change corresponding to the contents'string changed, however, the width is not enough, as to cover the last character of the string. How to solve this weird and annoying problem?

Thank you very much.

[image]

as the pic shows, The string should be "lzo", but the "o" is overlapped by the arrow partially.

Comment: You can show an image of what you get to understand you better. :P

Comment: i have add a pic. the "o" is overlapped by the arrow

Comment: I would recommend putting a better picture. Are you using stylesheet()?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem, though the method seems to be a little bit awkward. I manually added the spare space at the end of the line, and it worked.